# Distinct() returning char rather than element

Tags: c#, distinct

I am trying to figure out why Distinct() works here:

```
 string[] words= new string[] {"Cupcake","Cake","Candy", "Candy"};

      var uniqueWords = 
         from word in words
         orderby word
         select word; 

      foreach (var word in uniqueWords.Distinct())
      {
         Console.Write($" {word}");
```

But not here:

```
        var uniqueWords = from c in array
                          orderby c
                          select c.Distinct();

        foreach (var element in uniqueWords) 
                Console.WriteLine($"{element}");
```

I get the System.Linq.Enumerable+DistinctIterator`1[System.Char] console output

I have tried casting result but no success.

Comment: What do you expect `c.Distinct()` to return, exactly? (I don't see in what way it's "returning char" as per your title, either...)

Comment: It's returning a `char` in the second example (or rather, a sequence of sequences of distinct characters) because that's what the code says to do. In the first example, the `Distinct()` method is applied to the original sequence of `string` values. In the second, it's being applied to each individual `string` value, which are themselves sequences of `char` values.

Comment: How is `array` declared?

Comment: `var foo = from word in words orderby word select word.ToCharArray().Distinct();` <-- That's basically what you're doing in the first statement of your second code block (assuming `array == words`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your select here is select c.Distinct() as in select all the distinct characters from the string c:

```
var uniqueWords = from c in array
                      orderby c
                      select c.Distinct();
```

So if for example your item is "Cupcake" the distinct of this is an array of char:

'C','u','p','c','a','k','e'

You need to do:

```
(from c in array orderby c select c).Distinct()
```

Comment: I see my mistake. I was applying distinct to the selection rather than the var result

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it :)

Comment: Thank you very much